# Auto-Disable spell checking in help text

Tags: vim

I have enabled spelling in vim for .txt files, but would like to have set nospell when viewing helpfiles because my standard language setting is german, so most helptext is marked as misspelled. I have to issue .set nospell whenever I consult help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could create vim `autocmd`'s using the documentation directory as part of the file pattern. For example:

```
autocmd BufEnter /usr/share/vim/vim73/doc/*.txt  set nospell
autocmd BufLeave /usr/share/vim/vim73/doc/*.txt  set spell
```

The first entry should turn off spell check when entering the buffer of a helpfile. The second should turn it back on when you leave the buffer.

For more help with auto-commands checkout `:h autocmd`.

Comment: I have added the following lines to my .vimrc, since I use pathogen to manage all plugins so there are docfiles inside ~/.vim/bundle:

    autocmd BufEnter /usr/share/vim/vim73/doc/*.txt  set nospell
    autocmd BufEnter ~/.vim/bundle/*                 set nospell
    autocmd BufLeave /usr/share/vim/vim73/doc/*.txt  set spell
    autocmd BufLeave ~/.vim/bundle/*                 set spell

Answer (score 22):

You can put in your `.vimrc` an auto command to disable spell locally for help files. (This is actually a filetype):

```
autocmd FileType help setlocal nospell
```

I prefer this method because

1. it does not use any hard-coded path
2. the `nospell` option is only tied to current buffer (or window), so you don't have to check wether you enter or leave the buffer.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `setlocal`. I was enabling spell checking for markdown files in ~/.vim/ftplugin/markdown.vim via `set spell`. However, this enables it globally and it remains on in other types of files. `setlocal` fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

To disable in current file:

```
:setlocal nospell
```